# How to check if property exists

Tags: c#

I'm trying to read properties from `DirectoryEntry`.
Unfortunately not all records have `employeeNumber` property so I need to check if it exists.
I already tried:

```
a == one DirectoryEntry record
a.GetType().GetProperty("employeeNumber")==null //always returns true
String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(a.Properties["employeeNumber"].ToString()) //exception
```

what else can I try?

Comment: Properties are usually written with PascalCasing, not camelCasing. How is your property defined?

Comment: @OndrejJanacek in my case property is in camelCase

Comment: Can you try `bool doesExist = a.Properties.Contains("employeeNumber");`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can try like this:

```
OBJECT.GetType().GetProperty("PROPERTY") != null
```

So in your code it would be like:

```
var a = one DirectoryEntry record;
var pi = a.GetType().GetProperty("employeeNumber");
var value = pi.GetValue(a, null);
```

**EDIT:-**

Try this:

```
bool x = a.Properties.Contains("employeeNumber");
```

Comment: It's not about reflection. It's about Active Directory.

Comment: GetValue throws NullPointerException

Comment: @UlugbekUmirov:- Got that: bool x = a.Properties.Contains("employeeNumber"); What about this?

Comment: @szpic:- Try this:- bool x = a.Properties.Contains("employeeNumber");

Comment: Thx put this in answer and I'll accept

Comment: Propperties.contains only works when the attribute is not null.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
a.Properties["employeeNumber"] == null || a.Properties["employeeNumber"].ToString().Length == 0
```

In your case `a.Properties["employeeNumber"]` can be `null` and you get an exception, trying to convert `null` to string.

Comment: left side always returns false even if there is no `employeeNumber` right side is error because property doesn't have Length property